# Build Docker Image with Buildkit From Go Code

Tags: docker, go, build, docker-buildkit

I would like to build a Dockerfile using moby lib and buildkit with golang but I am struggling to mix both components together.

I saw that the types.ImageBuildOptions gets the Version option referenced as "2" in the documentation if you want to use buildkit.

https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/8d070e30f5a7e8aaa3dd3dd431f98b8c8909fbe2/docs/api/version-history.md?plain=1#L90-L93

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/docker/docker/api/types"
    "github.com/docker/docker/api/types/container"

    "github.com/docker/docker/client"
    "github.com/docker/docker/pkg/archive"
    "github.com/docker/docker/pkg/jsonmessage"
    "golang.org/x/net/context"
)
func main() {
...
    fmt.Print(cli.ClientVersion())
    buildOptions := types.ImageBuildOptions{
        SuppressOutput: false,
        NoCache:        false,
        Tags:           tags,
        PullParent:     true,
        Memory:         memory,
        MemorySwap:     memorySwap,
        Dockerfile:     dockerfile,
        BuildArgs:      args,
        Version:        "2",
    }
    _, err = cli.ImageBuild(context.Background(), nil, buildOptions)
...
}
```

If I run it, there is an error mentioning:

`~/code/ failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: no active sessions`

Then I referenced to the official builkit example here:
https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/examples/build-using-dockerfile/main.go

But I find it hard to understand what of the components of the example need to be in place to use it along my docker client